# Can I use i386 Ubuntu to install ARM software?

Tags: chroot

I have an Ubuntu machine, and I am trying to figure out how to modify a root filesystem that's eventually going to be on an embedded system running on an ARM processor. I have just a bare fs at the moment so I want to put things like a desktop environment on it and things before running on the embedded platform itself. I've gotten as far as extracting the fs archive into a directory, but am at a loss on how to proceed.

Googling had led me to believe I might be able to do this by using the chroot command to put my root in the mounted filesystem, and then maybe I could just use apt-get or something to install things, but that hasn't really worked. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Simulate arm (processor) https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=simulate+arm ← Several suggestions. ...